# what are key command in interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, interface-builder

On the right side bar of Interface builder; when a View Controller there is a "Key Commands" panel.
What is it?

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qnh3xkhnd4sl73q/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202015-03-06%2016.22.16.png?dl=0]

Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is list of key commands that trigger actions on the responder.

You can look to Apple documentation at UIResponder class and it's "keyCommands" property:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIResponder/keyCommands

Or you can go through some tutorial how to use this feature, like this one:
http://www.danandcheryl.com/2014/04/how-and-why-to-implement-keyboard-shortcuts-in-ios-7